# Automapper loads ignored lazy NHibernate property

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, automapper

I have the following scenario.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class FooDTO
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IList<BarDTO> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

I ignore the collection Bars

```
CreateMap<Foo,FooDTO>().ForMember(x => x.Bars, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Bars is lazy loading and is mapped with BarsDTO. If i only load the Foo entity from Database I only get the Name value. But when the mapping happens I see in SQL Profiler that all Bars are loaded from Database but are not mapped to DTO.

Why Automapper loads the ignored property?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works correctly. In FooDTO is another property which is called BarsCount and Automapper maps count automatically. So I have to delete BarsCount from DTO or also ignore it in mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading requires an associated NHibernate ISession open.

Can you send the code of the repository in question that manages the recovery of the data to map DTO

[NHibernate proxy lazy loading map to dto object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387296/automapper-dto-with-an-nhibernate-proxy?rq=1)